# What is the Best Tool to Automate HTML5 Backwards Compatibility Testing in Various Browsers

Tags: html, cross-browser, backwards-compatibility, modernizr

I'm using Modernizr to make my HTML5 site backwards compatible.  It's great, but is there a tool to run automated, headless tests which will parse my HTML for HTML5 features, then test each my code and its features in numerous browsers, and generate a report that I can use to add any polyfills I may have left off or know that I've successfully covered all of my bases using Modernizr?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, no. Such a tool has not been made publicly available by anyone.

Even if there was, it would be extremely difficult to do properly. Some things have polyfills that shouldn't be used (see rounded corners and OldIE), or the polyfills that do exist may not be needed in some/most cases.

This is something that is best left to the developer to properly check and test during development.

My basic workflow whenever I am using a feature that I am unsure of, is

1. check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com), comparing the data to my own analytics to determine if I even need to detect it. if no - stop. If yes...
2. Add the Modernizr test for that feature. If a polyfill is needed, then...
3. Add [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com) test, loading one of the polyfills listed in the metadata filed of Modernizr v3 detect.
4. rinse, wash, repeat

Comment: I just found out about http://html5test.com/, but it's not at all what I'm looking for.  I think the best hope is Modernizr and yepnope tests for the time being.  I think this would be a great open source project.

Comment: http://browsershots.org/ might help people quickly do a visual check of their site on different devices.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ for improved speed suggestions on your site.